# Old Mac Software So can't Use Databases (Xcode)(SQL)

Tags: sql, macos, sqlite, swift2, xcode6

I have swift 2.1 and my Xcode is v6 my mac is v10.1.1. I am doing a school project on Xcode code at the moment and I know I can't post the application on the app store so please don't comment on that; thank you. The problem I am facing is that due to my old mac I cant import anything and or download anything therefore when I try to make a login section to my news reader application I am facing trouble. I cant import sqlite as it needs news software and I cant use SQL as all the SQL type tools need newer software. I want a database on my mac which I can code. To do well on the project I need to my code more complex so If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

On a side note; my app is basically a news reader which parses in words to a api which brings back news articles which can be clicked on and opened in a web view, can anyone give me any suggestions that would make this more complex?

Comment: The question lacks clarity, and multiple questions are being asked and information is lacking

Answer (score -1):

All mac's can install MySQL, as its based on a linux system (I think some come with it pre installed?)

This site sadly isnt for making suggestions on what kind of complexcity should be added to your app but more for general technical questions and errors

Follow this homebrew guide: https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e

Comment: well i cant as i tried a few min ago and it told me my os is out of date

Comment: Edit my answer follow that link